# Convexity of even power sum symmetric functions

Tags: convex-analysis, symmetric-polynomials

I’ve been trying to decide, unsuccessfully, if the symmetric power sum functions, corresponding to partitions with even parts, are convex. In other words, is the polynomial $p_\lambda(x)$ convex where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda$ is a partition with only even parts? I appreciate your help.

Recall that $p_\lambda(x)=\prod_{i=1}^k{x_1^{\lambda_i}+\dots+x_n^{\lambda_i}}$ and in this case the $\lambda_i$ are even positive integers.

If $\lambda$ consists of one part then it’s true since the Hessian is obviously positive semidefinite.

Note $\log(p_\lambda)$ is not necessarily convex.

Comment: The product of two convex functions with codomain $\mathbb R_+$ is convex. Thus, the one-part case should be sufficient, right?

Comment: Thank you Darij! I knew it was a silly question. I just came across the result that *normalized* Schur polynomials were Lorentzian and I was wondering about similar properties for other families of symmetric polynomials.

Comment: $x^2$ and $y^2$ are convex with codomain $\mathbb{R}_+$ but $x^2y^2$ is not convex.